# i cannot get the complete word matched to be printed in the matchobject (regex python)

Tags: regex, python-2.7

when i execute 'm.group()' , if the pattern matches, then the pattern is printed and not the word to which it is matching. could someone please help?

```
import sys
import re

def main():

  str = sys.argv[1]
  m = re.search(str,'this is a sample text')
  print m.group()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

[OUTPUT:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpj3L.png)

Comment: OUTPUT:
C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\Python_stuff>re.py tex
tex

Comment: Are you trying to print aword containing a pattern? Use `str = r'\b\w*' + re.escape(sys.argv[1]) + r'\w*'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [re.**findall**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead like this:

**re.py:**

```
import sys
import re

def main():
  str = sys.argv[1]
  for word in re.findall(r"\w+", 'this is a sample text'):
    if str in word:
      print word

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Example usage:**

```
C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\Python_stuff>re.py tex
text
```